# How to analyze a MariaDB crash log?

Tags: mariadb

When I created a partition for an existing table, I got an exception stack below:

```
Thread pointer: 0x1ce1ecc6ab8
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
mysqld.exe!ha_partition::read_par_file()[ha_partition.cc:3021]
mysqld.exe!ha_partition::get_from_handler_file()[ha_partition.cc:3161]
mysqld.exe!ha_partition::initialize_partition()[ha_partition.cc:512]
mysqld.exe!partition_create_handler()[ha_partition.cc:185]
mysqld.exe!get_new_handler()[handler.cc:302]
mysqld.exe!TABLE_SHARE::init_from_binary_frm_image()[table.cc:2025]
mysqld.exe!open_table_def()[table.cc:698]
mysqld.exe!tdc_acquire_share()[table_cache.cc:842]
mysqld.exe!open_table()[sql_base.cc:1905]
mysqld.exe!open_and_process_table()[sql_base.cc:3802]
mysqld.exe!open_tables()[sql_base.cc:4300]
mysqld.exe!mysql_alter_table()[sql_table.cc:9353]
mysqld.exe!Sql_cmd_alter_table::execute()[sql_alter.cc:510]
mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:6087]
mysqld.exe!Prepared_statement::execute()[sql_prepare.cc:4760]
mysqld.exe!Prepared_statement::execute_loop()[sql_prepare.cc:4246]
mysqld.exe!mysql_sql_stmt_execute()[sql_prepare.cc:3364]
mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:3901]
mysqld.exe!sp_instr_stmt::exec_core()[sp_head.cc:3652]
mysqld.exe!sp_lex_keeper::reset_lex_and_exec_core()[sp_head.cc:3335]
mysqld.exe!sp_instr_stmt::execute()[sp_head.cc:3513]
mysqld.exe!sp_head::execute()[sp_head.cc:1346]
mysqld.exe!sp_head::execute_procedure()[sp_head.cc:2288]
mysqld.exe!do_execute_sp()[sql_parse.cc:3005]
mysqld.exe!Sql_cmd_call::execute()[sql_parse.cc:3247]
mysqld.exe!mysql_execute_command()[sql_parse.cc:6087]
mysqld.exe!sp_instr_stmt::exec_core()[sp_head.cc:3652]
mysqld.exe!sp_lex_keeper::reset_lex_and_exec_core()[sp_head.cc:3335]
mysqld.exe!sp_instr_stmt::execute()[sp_head.cc:3513]
mysqld.exe!sp_head::execute()[sp_head.cc:1346]
mysqld.exe!sp_head::execute_procedure()[sp_head.cc:2288]
mysqld.exe!Event_job_data::execute()[event_data_objects.cc:1459]
mysqld.exe!Event_worker_thread::run()[event_scheduler.cc:312]
mysqld.exe!event_worker_thread()[event_scheduler.cc:268]
mysqld.exe!pthread_start()[my_winthread.c:62]
ucrtbase.dll!_configthreadlocale()
KERNEL32.DLL!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0x1ce21cf66b8): alter table mytable add PARTITION (PARTITION t20221103 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DAYS("2022-11-03")+1))
Connection ID (thread ID): 1649
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

The running platform is windows so I cannot debug the core file.
Therefore, I read the source code but I cannot understand the reason still deeply.

The database version is 10.4.6 so here is the source code link:

> https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/mariadb-10.4.6/sql/ha_partition.cc#L3021

```cpp
  chksum= 0;
  for (i= 0; i < len_words; i++)
    chksum ^= uint4korr((file_buffer) + PAR_WORD_SIZE * i);
  if (chksum)
    goto err2;
  m_tot_parts= uint4korr((file_buffer) + PAR_NUM_PARTS_OFFSET);
  DBUG_PRINT("info", ("No of parts: %u", m_tot_parts));
  tot_partition_words= (m_tot_parts + PAR_WORD_SIZE - 1) / PAR_WORD_SIZE;

  tot_name_len_offset= file_buffer + PAR_ENGINES_OFFSET +
                       PAR_WORD_SIZE * tot_partition_words;
  tot_name_words= (uint4korr(tot_name_len_offset) + PAR_WORD_SIZE - 1) /
                  PAR_WORD_SIZE;  // <--- crashed here
```

There are some macros, so I don't know whether the line number is exact.
It seems a bug for loading the par file. I found that the above code has checked the validation on the par file, but subsequently, MariaDB still raises the exception.
So, I wonder if my analysis is right and how to bypass the exception, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

First is to [search existing bug reports for 'read_par_file'](https://jira.mariadb.org/issues/?jql=text%20%7E%20%22read_par_file%22), and there's no obvious match.

Second is, looking at the line it crashed, we can assume its reading from memory that isn't allocated. The `file_buffer` was allocated earlier in the file based of a word length at the beginning.

Third, if you look at the [git blame of the function](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blame/10.4/sql/ha_partition.cc#L2984), you see nothing has changed in quite a while.

So its likely a new bug. Please [report it](https://jira.mariadb.org) using the `show create table` and `par` file.

To confirm, that the `show create table mytable`, paste that into a running 10.4 latest version (containers are good for this). Then issue your alter table statement again. Its likely to crash, but its good to confirm.

There does seem to be a lack of checking around some of these offsets with regard to the allocated space.

Given it looks like you are doing daily partitions, have you exceeded the [maximum partitions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/partitioning-limitations/) of 8k per table? Either way, an error message should occur rather than a crash.

Comment: Thank you! I will recheck it and report it if it is a bug.

Comment: Hi, I haven't seen your bug report. I'm looking forward to ensuring this crash can be fixed for you and everyone else that does a similar thing.